# How to flatten a list of dict and get specific text

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a pandas dataframe with 2 columns. The first is an id and the second column contains a list of nested dict and some rows have NaN value. My dataframe have a lot of rows so below you will find a snapshot.

| Id | list_dict |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | NaN |
| 2 | [{'type': 'paragraph','content': [{'type': 'text','text': 'XXX'}]},{'type': 'paragraph','content': [{'type': 'text','text': 'XXX'}]},{'type': 'paragraph','content': [{'type': 'hardBreak'},{'type': 'text','text': 'XXX'},{'type': 'hardBreak'}]},{'type': 'paragraph','content': [{'type': 'text','text': 'XXX'}]}] |
| 3 | NaN |

My goal is to get the key ('text'), value ('XXX') and concatenate the values (XXX XXX XXX). Please keep in mind that value XXX is a text so in every value('text') I have different content.

Comment: what have you tried so far

Comment: I tried json_normalize but I get some errors because of NaN values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is similar, but considers all the keys `text`, not only in the first entry of `content`. And should be safe in case `content` is an empty list.

```
import json

def extract_texts(list_dict):
    if not isinstance(list_dict, list):
        return list_dict
    
    result = []
    for entry in list_dict:
        for content in entry.get("content", []) :
            if "text" in content:
                result.append(content["text"])
    
    return " ".join(result)

df["list_dict"].apply(extract_texts)
```

Output:

```
0                NaN
1    XXX XXX XXX XXX
2                NaN
```